# position hyperlink images to Shiny Dashboard header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I"m relatively new to ShinyDashboards and am getting confused with the HTML tags.  And formatting.

I finally got it working to have 3 hyperlinked logos in my header.  But they were positioned vertically to each other.  To try and position them horizontally besides each other, I thought I could put them in fluidRow, but that doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

```
  dashboardHeader(title="Title",
    # Set height of dashboardHeader
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",
            tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 100px}"),
            tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px}")
    ),
    fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
      tags$li(class="dropdown",
            tags$a(href = linkedIn_address,
              img(src ="linkedIn_logo_trans.png",
              title = "LinkedIn",height="30px")),
           tags$a(href = google_scholar_address,
              img(src = 'google_scholar_icon.png',
                  title = "Google Scholar", height = "30px"),
              style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"),
          tags$a(href = email_address,
          img(src = 'email_icon_transparent.png',
              title = "Email", height = "30px"),
          style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;")
        )
      ))
),
```

Comment: Try separate `tags$li()` for each link.  No need of column or fluidRow().